# read key value pairs from a text file in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given `superset` and `superset2` input text files. `Superset` is having all the required headers (`keys`).

Rows from `superset2` file may be missing value for some column in header, need to fill missing value with `$` character.

A. superset:

```
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j
```

B. superset2:

```
a:1,b:1,d:1,e:1,h:1
a:2,e:2,d:2,h:2,f:2
c:3,e:3,d:3,h:3,f:3
a:4,b:4,c:4,e:4,h:4,f:4,i:4,j:4
```

Expected output:

```
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j
1|1|$|1|1|$|$|1|$|$
2|$|$|2|2|2|$|2|$|$
$|$ |3|3|3|3|$|3|$|$
4|4|4|$|4|4|$|4|4|4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the 2 files into Dataframes and:

1. get the list of keys (columns) of the the first dataframe
2. do some transformations on the second dataframe which contains the data, by splitting the values first by `,` then second by `:` using combination of `transform` and `map_from_entries` functions to convert each row into a map column
3. finally using list comprehension on the list of keys select the columns and `fillna` to replace nulls by `$`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


keys = spark.read.csv(keys_file_path, sep="|", header=True).columns
data = spark.read.text(data_file_path)

df = data.withColumn(
    "value",
    F.map_from_entries(
        F.expr("""transform(
                        split(value , ','), 
                        x -> struct(split(x, ':')[0] as col, split(x, ':')[1] as val)
        )""")
    )
).select(*[
    F.col("value").getItem(k).alias(k) for k in keys
]).fillna("$")

df.show(truncate=False)
#+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
#|a  |b  |c  |d  |e  |f  |g  |h  |i  |j  |
#+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
#|1  |1  |$  |1  |1  |$  |$  |1  |$  |$  |
#|2  |$  |$  |2  |2  |2  |$  |2  |$  |$  |
#|$  |$  |3  |3  |3  |3  |$  |3  |$  |$  |
#|4  |4  |4  |$  |4  |4  |$  |4  |4  |4  |
#+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```